# How can i create a macro in hive for this used case?

Tags: sql, hive, macros, hiveql

I have the following query with repeated case when statements, I would like to create macro for this

```
 select  
    *, 
    
    case when s1 between 0 and  40 then 'low'
      when s1 between 41 and  80 then 'medium'
    when s1 between 81 and  100 then 'high'
    end as first_segment , 
    
    
    case when s2 between 0 and  40 then 'low'
      when s2 between 41 and  80 then 'medium'
    when s2 between 81 and  100 then 'high'
    end as s_segement 
                      
              
      from   

table
```

i tried this but it does not work. where x is a column

```
CREATE TEMPORARY MACRO bucket(x INT)
   case when x between 0 and  40 then 'low'
      when x between 41 and  80 then 'medium'
    when x between 81 and  100 then 'high'
    end as x+'_'+'bucket';
```

is the INT referring to the content of column type? The above macro does not work..

```
ParseException line 5:8 missing EOF at 'as' near 'end'
```

Comment: Macros are essentially functions.  You don't get to name the results.

Comment: so i can't have this act on a column 'x' - is there a way to optimize the above query somehow/make efficient

Answer (score 0):

Add macro alias in the query:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY MACRO bucket(x INT)
   case when x between 0  and  40  then 'low'
        when x between 41 and  80  then 'medium'
        when x between 81 and  100 then 'high'
    end;

select bucket(s1) as first_segment,
       bucket(s2) as s_segement,
 from ...
```